# Remove_Widget is not working

Tags: python, kivy

I have highlighted a line below where remove_widget is not functioning correctly. I believe that I have accessed the Class correctly. However, I am unable to add or remove a widget with the code below.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import random
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, AliasProperty 

class LargeGrid(GridLayout):
    cols = 8
    rows = 8

def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(LargeGrid,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    for i in range(64):
        self.add_widget(Button(text=str(i), on_press=buttonPress))

class SmallGrid(BoxLayout): 
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(SmallGrid,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(8):
             self.add_widget(Button(text=str(i), background_color= (random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), 1.0)))

def buttonPress(obj):
    smallGrid = SmallGrid()
    sel = smallGrid.children[-1]

    #These lines work
    obj.background_color = sel.background_color
    obj.text = sel.text

    #This line is not working properly
    smallGrid.remove_widget(sel)

    root = Builder.load_string('''

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        text: "Logo"
        size_hint: (1, .1)   
    SmallGrid:
        orientation: 'vertical'

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        text: "Settings"
        size_hint: (1, .1)

    LargeGrid:

 ''')


 class MyApp(App):

     def build(self):
          return root

 MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Please clean your example. Ton of imports you dont even use. And irrelevant comments and what not Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Cleaned up a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new smallgrid, instead of editing the existing one.
Also I changed the structure of your program a bit. The `buttonPress` should be a method of the `SmallGrid` class instead.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import random


class MyButton(Button):
    pass


class LargeGrid(GridLayout):
    cols = 8
    rows = 8

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(LargeGrid,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(64):
            self.add_widget(MyButton(text=str(i)))


class SmallGrid(BoxLayout): 
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(SmallGrid,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(8):
             self.add_widget(Button(text=str(i), background_color= (random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), 1.0)))


    def buttonPress(self,obj):
        sel = self.children[-1]

        obj.background_color = sel.background_color
        obj.text = sel.text

        self.remove_widget(sel)


root = Builder.load_string('''

<MyButton>:
    on_release:
        app.root.ids.smallgrid.buttonPress(self)


BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Button:
            text: "Logo"
            size_hint: (1, .1)   
        SmallGrid:
            id: smallgrid
            orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Button:
            text: "Settings"
            size_hint: (1, .1)

        LargeGrid:

 ''')


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return root

MyApp().run()
```